# How to define functions based on attribute to elixir?

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's say I have a modules `Silent` and `Definer`. I want to define a couple of functions for `Silent`, based on its attribute. Let me explain:

```
defmodule Silent do
  @function_names [:a, :b, :c]

  use Definer
end

defmodule Definer do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      Enum.each(@function_names, fn(n) ->
        def unquote(n)() do # line 5
          IO.puts "a new method is here!"
        end
      end)
    end
  end
end
```

But this approach actually doesn't work because I have `undefined function n/0 on line 5`. How can I implement desired functionality?

Comment: I would love to know what the use case is for this.  Are you trying to do some sort of poor man's interface?  If so, you probably should look at Elixir's protocols: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `unquote: false` to `quote` in `Definer.__using__/1` to be able to inject an `unquote` fragment inside a `quote`.

```
defmodule Definer do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote unquote: false do
      Enum.each(@function_names, fn(n) ->
        def unquote(n)() do # line 5
          IO.puts "a new method is here!"
        end
      end)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Silent do
  @function_names [:a, :b, :c]

  use Definer
end

Silent.a
Silent.b
Silent.c
```

prints

```
a new method is here!
a new method is here!
a new method is here!
```

A similar case is documented in detail in the [Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2 docs](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/a6411efce54c8ff8e162142ba638e04a54c87027/lib/elixir/lib/kernel/special_forms.ex#L1194-L1228) which also mentions how to use `bind_quoted` if you want to both inject some variables into a `quote` and create `unquote` fragments.